# Ruby - Set key-value pairs inside array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator, ruby-hash

The problem is:
I have a method

```
def comparison_reporter(list_of_scenarios_results1, list_of_scenarios_results2)
  actual_failed_tests = list_of_scenarios_results2.select {|k,v| v == 'Failed'}
  actual_passed_tests = list_of_scenarios_results2.select {|k,v| v == 'Passed'}
  failed_tests = Array.new(actual_failed_tests.length) { Hash.new }
  failed_tests.each do |hash|
      actual_failed_tests.keys.map {|name| hash["test_name"] = name}
      actual_failed_tests.values.map {|new_status| hash["actual_status"] = new_status}
      list_of_scenarios_results1.values_at(*actual_failed_tests.keys).map {|old_status| hash["previous_status"] = old_status}
  end
  final_result = {
    "passed_tests_count" => list_of_scenarios_results2.select {|k,v| v == 'Passed'}.length,
    "failed_tests_count" => list_of_scenarios_results2.select {|k,v| v == 'Failed'}.length,
    "failed_tests" => failed_tests
  }
  return final_result
end
```

This method takes 2 hashes as arguments and returns the result of their comparison and some other things. Currently, it always returns `failed_tests` with two (or more) identical hashes (same key-value pairs).
I think, that problem is somewhere in `failed_tests.each do |hash|` block, but I can't find the reason of this bug, please advice. Example of the method result (in .json format)

```
{
  "passed_tests_count": 3,
  "failed_tests_count": 2,
  "failed_tests": [
    {
      "test_name": "As a user I want to use Recent searches tab",
      "actual_status": "Failed",
      "previous_status": "Failed"
    },
    {
      "test_name": "As a user I want to use Recent searches tab",
      "actual_status": "Failed",
      "previous_status": "Failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

UPD:
hash1 (first argument) -

```
{""=>"Passed",
"As a new user I want to use no fee rentals tab"=>"Passed",
"As a new user I want to use Luxury rentals tab"=>"Passed", 
"As a user I want to use Recent searches tab"=>"Failed",
"As a user I want to use new listings for you tab"=>"Passed"}
```

hash2 (second argument)-

```
{""=>"Passed",
"As a new user I want to use no fee rentals tab"=>"Failed",
"As a new user I want to use Luxury rentals tab"=>"Passed",
"As a user I want to use Recent searches tab"=>"Failed",
"As a user I want to use new listings for you tab"=>"Passed"}
```

Example of desired desired output:

```
{ 
"passed":"count",
"failed":"count",
"failed_tests": [
   {"test_name":"As a user I want to use Recent searches tab",
    "actual_status":"failed",
    "previous_status":"failed"},
   {"test_name":"As a new user I want to use no fee rentals tab",
    "actual_status":"failed",
    "previous_status":"passed"}]
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you have in somewhere in `failed_tests.each do |hash|` block? You haven't stated it. What do you expect the method to do?

Comment: Yep, sorry. The method should return `final_result` which should also contain `failed_tests` array with 2 different hashes (results and comparison for different tests). Currently, as you can see from the example - both hashes are actually the same, therefore I thought that smthn is wrong in `failed_tests.each do |hash|`

Comment: @Mikhah it's nice that you showed effort, but it's difficult to read through your method. If you want an answer, provide your input (the 2 hashes) and the hash you'd like to be the result.

Comment: @sawa ofc, I've updated the question

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej sorry, missclicked) I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
def comparison_reporter(before, after)
  failed_tests = after.select { |k,v| v == "Failed" }.map do |k,v|
    {
      test_name: k,
      actual_status: v,
      previous_status: before[k]
    }
  end

  {
    passed: after.size - failed_tests.size,
    failed: failed_tests.size,
    failed_tests: failed_tests
  }
end
```

Simplified `failed_tests` quite a bit. Since we calculate number of failed tests, we can use it for the final counts, instead of iterating over the hash again.

Comment: Thanks for the simplification and answer, it works perfectly)

Comment: Perhaps `...after.each_with_object([]) { |(k,v),a| a << { test_name: k,actual_status: v, previous_status: before[k] } if v=="Failed" }` to traverse the array just once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on line 8: You're overwriting `hash["previous_status"]` with the last value in `list_of_scenarios_results1.values_at(*actual_failed_tests.keys)` when you map over it.

Usually you use map to assign an iterable to something, not modify something else.
e.g.
`x = ['1','2','3'].map(&:to_i)`
rather than
`x = []; ['1','2','3'].map {|v| x << v.to_i}`

I'd suggest re-thinking your approach. Will you always have the same keys in both hashes? If so you could simplify this. I'd also suggest looking into [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). It's an interactive debugger that'll let you step through your function and see where things aren't doing what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely use byebug in future